# Translate 主播 in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

This article is talking about speaking books, e-books.

与国外相比，中国的有声书产业尚处于起步阶段，行业规模和标准亟待统一。此外，优秀主播的培养也是一大缺口。

Normally, 主播 refers to a TV or radio anchor person, the host of a show. That makes no sense to me here.

此外，优秀主播的培养也是一大缺口。
Also, there is a big shortfall （缺口） of training （培养） for outstanding （优秀）readers （主播）.

主播：here the people who originally read the recording? Is that correct, or am I missing something?

Why not write: 阅读者？

Comment: A side-note, 阅读 usually refers to reading in silence.  朗诵 means reading something out aloud.

Comment: I think the use of 主播 is ok for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 有声书, 主播 is not just a simple reader(阅读者). They are more like 说评书者 in the past. Back in the day, 说评书者 is kind of story teller. Usually they tell stories from those ancient novels on TV or radio. Nowadays, they pick all kinds of story books on variety of medias. 网络有声书 is a new popular media they are mostly focusing on now because of a large number of netizens out there.

So, the term 主播 is more appropriate because 主播 can be a key factor to the success of a 有声书.

Comment: I own a few English aduiobooks, The "narrator"  (叙述者) only read what is printed on the book There's no  commentary in these books. Unless Chinese aduiobooks are different, 主播 (program host) cannot be the correct term.

Comment: @TangHo I often listen to those 有声书 on 喜马拉雅. They all call 主播.

Comment: Which mean they didn't translate the term correctly-- Do they treat the book reading like a 书评, provide commentary? If they only read what is written in a book, 主播 would not be  an appropriate term. Since I don't have any Chinese audiobook. I cannot definitely say your answer is wrong. May be Chinese audiobooks do work like a commentated program?

Comment: @TangHo Some are boring, some of them are like 评书. But it seems that they are all called 主播 or 播讲人.

Comment: I think that calling them 主播 is to put an emphasis on the value of individual artistic expression of the narrator and reflects the often podcast-like nature of  some Chinese e-books. For example, when many narrators put out daily or weekly *episodes* reading books and individual narrators have their own fans/followers, it's easier to see why they are called hosts rather than simply narrators.

Comment: @zhantongz Yeah, those 有声书s read by machinery readers suck and really turn people off.  I personally never listen to them. :)

Answer (score 3):

You are correct. 主播 (anchor person/ program host) makes no sense in this context

The one who read out the content in an **有聲書** (Audiobook) should be called  "誦讀者" (one who recite text)

Or "朗讀者" (one who recite text in a clear voice) if the content is of poetic nature

阅读者 mainly mean the one who read (with eyes, not reading out with voice)

I own a few Audiobooks, the one who read the book out is listed as "narrator" (叙述者), So. 叙述者 could be used in Chinese Audiobooks titles too